# Pyarrow: how to cast data type in a structType?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a parquet file, when i read data from it i get the following schema:

```
pyarrow.Table
schema0: struct<crm: struct<task: struct<ACTIVITY_STATUS: string, CREATED_ON: timestamp[us], TASK_ID: string, esitoInfo: struct<ESITO: string>, timeInfo: struct<ACTUAL_END: null, DATA_SCADENZA_TASK: timestamp[us]>>, ticket: struct<TICKET_ID: string>>, eventType: string, identities: struct<ID_CONTO: string>>
  child 0, crm: struct<task: struct<ACTIVITY_STATUS: string, CREATED_ON: timestamp[us], TASK_ID: string,  esitoInfo: struct<ESITO: string>, timeInfo: struct<ACTUAL_END: null, DATA_SCADENZA_TASK: timestamp[us]>>, ticket: struct<TICKET_ID: string>>
      child 0, task: struct<ACTIVITY_STATUS: string, CREATED_ON: timestamp[us], TASK_ID: string,  esitoInfo: struct<ESITO: string>, timeInfo: struct<ACTUAL_END: null, DATA_SCADENZA_TASK: timestamp[us]>>
          child 0, ACTIVITY_STATUS: string
          child 1, CREATED_ON: timestamp[us]
          child 2, TASK_ID: string
          child 3, esitoInfo: struct<ESITO: string>
              child 0, ESITO: string
HERE      child 4, timeInfo: struct<ACTUAL_END: null, DATA_SCADENZA_TASK: timestamp[us]>          HERE
HERE          child 0, ACTUAL_END: null                                                           HERE
              child 1, DATA_SCADENZA_TASK: timestamp[us]
      child 1, ticket: struct<TICKET_ID: string>
          child 0, TICKET_ID: string
  child 1, eventType: string
  child 2, identities: struct<ID_CONTO: string>
      child 0, ID_CONTO: string
_id: string
timestamp: timestamp[us]
```

As you can see I have marked "here" the field which has column type "null", i would like to cast it as datetime even if all its elements are null (and therefore it is inferred as null).
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: `pyarrow.compute` has a `cast` function but I just tried it on something like this and it does not appear you can use it to change the type of a nested struct field.  You could maybe submit a JIRA but I think it would be preferable to avoid getting the invalid struct field type in the first place.

If I recall correctly, you are first reading in a large CSV and then splitting it.  It seems like the `null` struct type is getting introduced as part of your split operation (unless your large CSV has null for the entire column).  Can you provide some more details how you are splitting?

Comment: There is an existing JIRA issue about casting with struct type: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1888

Comment: @Pace yes you are right, i'm reading a big csv and splitting it using days as splitting criteria (therefore some days have all null records in a column). I've found you can force a datatype using ```table_parquet = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)``` and then ```pq.write_table(table_parquet, "output.parquet")```. The last problem was I didn't know how to write a nested schema. Luckily I had a parquet guideline file and I used its schema to guide the conversion from pandas. 
Maybe could be useful for me in the future if you can explain how to build nested schema :)